# Terabytes of data generated by Boeing Jet every hour

Tags: aviation, electronics, hardware

2010 article from gigaom (http://gigaom.com/2010/09/13/sensor-networks-top-social-networks-for-big-data-2/ Sensor Networks Top Social Networks for Big Data) says that twin engine Boeing Jet aircraft generates lot of information, 40 terabytes per hour:

> Boeing jet generates 10 terabytes of information per engine every 30 minutes of flight, according to Stephen Brobst, the CTO of Teradata. So for a single six-hour, cross-country flight from New York to Los Angeles on a twin-engine Boeing 737 — the plane used by many carriers on this route — the total amount of data generated would be a massive 240 terabytes of data.

Is it true that engine's sensors generates so lot data?

Is it true that all data generated by sensors are stored on-board (this will need 50+ hugest 4TB harddrives) or downloaded to Earth?

Comment: There's a third option: that the older data is discarded or summarised as the newer data is generated.

Comment: Ring buffers is probably the simple solution

Comment: "Boeing jet generates 10 terabytes of information per engine" - this claim is meaningless unless you specify what is meant by "information". If *recorded* information is meant this sounds not feasible at all.

Comment: According to this article http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Flight_Data_Recorder_(FDR). "It is now possible to have 2-hour audio CVRs and DFDRs that can record up to 256 12-bit data words per second, or 4 times the capacity of magnetic tape DFDRs." That's 1.3 megabyte per hour. 10 Tb of numbers is a humongous amount of data, and it feels useless because it would imply having tens of thousands of parameters recorded with sub-nanosecond resolution, well beyond the typical mechanical precision.

Comment: The only thing which can be interpreted that way is audio data which does take a lot of space. Lossless digital format storing audio recordings can be that big, but still the magnetic tapes are used for this and so such a way of interpreting data is not very fair, because magnetic tape is not exactly lossless either...

Comment: https://avoa.com/2014/01/20/are-enterprises-prepared-for-the-data-tsunami/ article have some numbers: "*[GE’s GEnx next generation turbofan engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Electric_GEnx) found on Boeing 787 and 747-8 aircraft contain some 5,000 data points that are analyzed every second.*" https://vrworld.com/2015/05/08/big-data-in-planes-new-pw-gtf-engine-telemetry-to-generate-10gbs/ also says 5000 sensors for  PW1000G GTF with "*10 GB/s per engine*" (???).